# Linux driver : Pipelining with delay

Tags: linux, drivers, pipe

I want to create a driver with non-blocking read/write. Input of pipe0 is connected to output of pipe1. On `write()` the data is written into the pipe after a delay(using a kernel timer or workqueue). Write delay needs to be controllable(get and set) via `ioctl()`. Finally, I want to measure the throughput of the driver with read/write buffer size set to 1 B, 1 KB, I MB with delay set to 0,1 ms and 1 sec.

I have read some tutorials on how to make driver for linux.

But,I am facing following problems :

1. How to first create a driver such that whenever any of the process generates output, my driver should read into the buffer.
2. How to pass this buffer's data as input to another program which is running.

Essentially I need to create a "piping driver with delay".

Normal piping works with symbol '|'. How can I create my own symbol such as 'a|b' when I want to implement my driver('a' is size of buffer and 'b' is delay which is set)

Something like : `ls myfile.txt 20|5 wc`

In above example 20 is 20 KB buffer size and 5 is 5 ms delay

Comment: If you believe that you are talking about a driver, you haven’t read enough tutorials.  A driver provides an interface between a process and a device.  OK, it’s true that you can have a driver for a pseudo-device, and that you can use that pseudo-device driver to provide an interface between two processes, but you don’t show any indication that you understand that or are planning to do it.  And do you even understand what non-blocking I/O ***is?***  It means that, if a requested operation cannot be performed immediately, it simply doesn’t happen at all — not that it is performed after a delay!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the system manages the FIFO size which typically defaults to 1MB.  You can check or change it with `sysctl fs.pipe-max-size [newsize]`.  This does not require any new program.

You also do not need to reinvent the wheel, the kernel, or the shell to apply your intended program.  If you decide to go through with that idea, you just run `command | yourbufferprogram | othercommand`.

Writing that program would simply involve `popen()` system calls and memory controls to buffer the data and count the throughput.  Give it a try and if you get stuck, post a more specific question on [StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com).

Finally, note that such a buffer could quickly cause memory usage to balloon up if there's more input data than expected!